# Change the CSS depending on page id in wordpress inside of a walker

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Currently I have in my functions.php

```
class Menu_With_Description extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        //$item_output .= '<span class="sub">' . $item->description . '</span>';
        $item_output .= '<img src="' . $item->description . '" />';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

On my Nav Menu at the moment it works perfectly as I want it too with my theme, however I want to make it just detect the page "About Us" and parse different set of code instead of the  statement. I tried to write an exclude function and than parse my own code before the walker statement on my header.php and it didn't work out too well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

`if (is_page($page_id)) { //page specific code here. }`

where `$page_id` is obviously your "About Us" page.

[wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

Comment: Going to try it now, I don't need to else the rest do I?

Comment: depends if you want that code to be executed on the "about us" page as well. Without an else, all the code will be executed for "about us".

Comment: I want to parse from $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>'; and down for anything that is NOT about us. If it is About Us, I want it do different things